# How to change spacing after section in Table of Contents?

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, tocloft

How to change the spacings on picture?

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[floatsubsection,equationsubsection,14pt,nocolumnsxix]{eskdtext}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\section}{\bf}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\bf}
\titlespacing*{\section}{13pt}{8mm}{8mm}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{15mm}{15mm}
\parindent=1,25cm
\linespread{1.25}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\cftsetindents{section}{0.5in}{0.5in}
\cftsetindents{subsection}{0.5in}{0.5in}
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\mdseries}
\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{\mdseries}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
dfgfgdfgsergtfsr
srthg
srdth
ert
h
resth
we
rth
wer
th
erth
d
\section{Slef}
\subsection{dfgsertgsergRERE}
\section{FCYITH}
\section*{Dnishe} 
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Dnishe}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As far as I know `titlesec` and `tocloft` do not really like each other

Comment: @Christian Hupfer, so what i have to use instead of titlesec for title spacing?

Comment: IIRC, the formatting for the toc is actually handled by \l@section and \l@subsection, which are defined by eskdtext.cls.

Comment: I did'nt found this code in eskdtext.cls file,so which commands must i use to define spacing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found i was looking for.
Here is my solution:

```
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftbeforesecskip}{0pt}%change indent between sections
\renewcommand{\cftdot}{}%remove dots
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to remove the dotted line from the toc, at least for article class.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@subsection[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\@ne
    \addpenalty\@secpenalty
    \addvspace{\z@ \@plus\p@}% vertical space (1.0em \@plus\p@ for section}
    \setlength\@tempdima{2.3em}% #3 from \@dottedtocline
    \begingroup
      \parindent 1.5em\relax% #2 from \@dottedtocline
      \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode \bfseries
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip
      #1\nobreak\hfil \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}\par
    \endgroup
  \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Slef}
\subsection{dfgsertgsergRERE}
\section{FCYITH}
\section*{Dnishe} 
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Dnishe}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

This replaces (from article.cls)

```
\newcommand*\l@subsection{\@dottedtocline{2}{1.5em}{2.3em}}
```

where (from source2e.pdf)

```
\@dottedtocline{⟨level⟩}{⟨indent⟩}{⟨numwidth⟩ }{⟨title⟩}{⟨page⟩}
```

Comment: i got a problem: with this code my subsection became bold and they losing left margin, which equals \parindent.Which part of code must i change to fix it7

Comment: Well, i found that method ,if i use tocloft,i can write \renewcommand{\cftdot}{}